# Reference SessionStorage using a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just wondering if it is possible to reference data stored as sessionStorage using a variable, something similar to this :-

```
var reference = "bar";
console.log ('sessionStorage.foo' + reference);
```

Comment: What exactly you want ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is that the same as local storage as well?or cookies?

Comment: @guradio: Yes. `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` are the same kind of thing, they just have different persistence scopes. Cookies are different, but they're also strings (with some metadata -- expiration and path).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to access the item `"foobar"` in your example, you can access session storage through `getItem` or using bracketed notation:

```
var data = sessionStorage.getItem("foo" + reference);
// or
var data = sessionStorage["foo" + reference];
```

If you're just looking to get the item `"bar"`, then:

```
var data = sessionStorage.getItem(reference);
// or
var data = sessionStorage[reference];
```